# Как сделать шкалу прогресса в виде заполняемых клеточек?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать шкалу прогресса в виде заполняемых клеточек, как в примере выше?
Можно привести единичный пример.

Comment: Ваша картинка примера не видна.

Answer (score 4):

Самый простой пример это использовать HTML5 тег [progress](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_progress.asp):

```css
.graph {
    width: 500px; /* width and height are arbitrary, just make sure the #bar styles are changed accordingly */
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #888; 
    background: rgb(168,168,168);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(168,168,168,1) 0%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 23%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(168,168,168,1)), color-stop(23%,rgba(204,204,204,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(168,168,168,1) 0%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 23%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(168,168,168,1) 0%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 23%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(168,168,168,1) 0%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 23%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a8a8a8', endColorstr='#cccccc',GradientType=0 );
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(168,168,168,1) 0%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 23%);
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
Статус
<progress value="34" max="100"><div id="progress" class="graph"><div id="bar" style="width:34%"><p>34% complete</p></div></div></progress>
```

[Источник](https://bl.ocks.org/stephenhay/1086250)

Answer (score 4):

Индикатор прогресса добавляется с помощью элемента . Значение индикатора определяется атрибутами value, min и max:

```
<progress value="10" max="100"></progress>
```

В таблице стилей мы можем использовать селектор элемента для выбора элемента и добавления правил для элемента . В ниже приведенном примере мы изменяем фоновый цвет, удаляем обводку и скругляем углы на радиус равный половине высоты элемента.

```
progress {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    border: 0;
    height: 18px;
    border-radius: 9px;
}
```

Однако, каждый браузер обрабатывает правила немного по своему.
Таким образом для изменения полоски индикатора и текущего значения в браузере нужно добавить псевдо-классы:

Вот пример общего рабочего кода прогресс бара.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Индикатор прогресса HTML5 | Материалы сайта RUSELLER.COM</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var progressbar = $('#progressbar'),
     max = progressbar.attr('max'),
     time = (1000/max)*5, 
           value = progressbar.val();

       var loading = function() {
           value += 1;
           addValue = progressbar.val(value);
           
           $('.progress-value').html(value + '%');

           if (value == max) {
               clearInterval(animate);              
           }
       };

       var animate = setInterval(function() {
           loading();
       }, time);
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="demo-wrapper html5-progress-bar">
  <div class="progress-bar-wrapper">
   <progress id="progressbar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
   <span class="progress-value">0%</span>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к ответу для HTML5 вот вариант на чистом HTML/CSS

```css
.label, .progress-bar, .progress-block  {
  float: left;
}
.label {
  margin-right: 50px;
}
.progress-block {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 2px 1px;
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
}
.progress-block.active {
  background-color: #B72F54;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='label'>PHOTOSHOP</div>
  <div class='progress-bar'>
    <div class='progress-block active'></div>
    <div class='progress-block active'></div>
    <div class='progress-block active'></div>
    <div class='progress-block active'></div>
    <div class='progress-block active'></div>
    <div class='progress-block active'></div>
    <div class='progress-block'></div>
    <div class='progress-block'></div>
    <div class='progress-block'></div>
    <div class='progress-block'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```